# Check if category of post is x or is child of x

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

My wordpress site has categories with a simple hierarchy –

- Blog

  - Role Shift
  - Urod the Last Show
  - News

I'm using the if statement below to catch if the post is in category blog or any of the child categories - and it works - but it feels stupid not to be able to just check the parent of the current category (plus I might want to add categories later).

```
if ( is_category('blog') || in_category(array('role-shift', 'urod-the-last-show', 'news')) )
```

I've searched and tried every suggestion - including `cat_is_ancestor_of` - but nothing is working.

Please help!

Robert

Answer (score 1):

```
$categories = get_the_category(); //returns categories
$thiscat = $categories[0];

$parent_id = $thiscat->parent; //the parent id
$parent = get_category($parent_id) //this returns the parent category as an object

//use id or slug of category you are searching for
if( $parent_id == 1 || $thiscat->slug == 'blog' ){
//this is a child of blog or the blog page
}
```

This should do the trick.
This will determine if the current category is a child of the blog page. 
The first part, get_category, returns the current category.

Then you can get the parent id from the current category and use 'get_the_category_by_ID' to get the parent category object.

Then you can check if you are under the parent category you want.

Comment: Thanks but that's not working - the if statement isn't catching anything so everything is falling under the else.

Comment: I made an update to the code that might fix it.
It does the same thing but gets the current and parent categories in a different way and checks against the slug instead.

Comment: Still nothing - but thanks anyway.

When I ask it to `echo $thiscat->slug;` I get the current category's slug, but `echo $parent->slug;` is empty.

Comment: Nice!
Good the hear.